# Easier way to center a label in Xul

Tags: xul

Is there an easier way to center a label in Xul then with the following?

```
<xul:hbox>
    <xul:spacer flex="1" />
    <xul:label id="myLabel" value="LABEL"/>
    <xul:spacer flex="1" />
</xul:hbox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Use box packing via [the pack attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Element_Positioning#Box_Packing).

```
<hbox pack="center"><label id="myLabel" value="LABEL"/></hbox.
```

Answer (score 1):

Two alternative ways which also work with multiline labels:

1. Use `<label style="text-align: center"/>`
2. Use `<vbox align="center"><label/></vbox>`